# SQL select all records from a sequence order by multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

from table below

```
id  firstname   lastname
1   john        smith
2   john        doe
3   john        fox
4   adam        white
5   brad        grant
6   michael     jordan
7   amy         young
```

how to select everyone before john fox order by firstname, lastname?
I came up with below but it looks really clumsy.

```
select * from student where firstname<'John'
union
select * from student where firstname='John' and lastname<='fox'
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want to base this on alphabetical ordering by firstname/lastname.  That seems strange but one method is:

```
select s.*
from student s
where firstname < 'john' or
      firstname = 'john' and lastname <= 'fox'
order by firstname, lastname;
```

Some databases support tuple comparisons, which allows:

```
select s.*
from student s
where (firstname, lastname) <= ('john', 'fox')
order by firstname, lastname;
```

Comment: my sql server is MS SQL 2012. It doesn't seem to support option 2 as I just tried. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Q.Young . . . SQL Server does not support tuple comparisons.

Comment: That's unfortunate. I really like the cleanness.